# MySQL query - Select a unique column comparing other column

Tags: mysql, optimization

I've a table with the following structure:

```
id  | property_id | location_type
1   | 1           | 1
2   | 1           | 2
3   | 2           | 1
4   | 3           | 2
5   | 4           | 1
6   | 4           | 2
```

id - is the primary key of the table. property_id is the property ID of my database (foreign key). location_type is beach (value - 1), mountain (value - 2)

Can you please help me in getting the SQL query to select the property_id with location_type = 1 AND location_type = 2 i.e. a property has beach and mountains.

I have lot of filters (around 9 types of location_type and other filters). I'm creating a property search engine with filters. Please help in getting the most optimized query so load time is less.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select
property_id
from table
where location_type in (1,2)
group by property_id
having count(distinct(location_type)) = 2
```

if you don't have duplicates you can remove distinct clause.

Comment: Won't this also select rows where there are two records, one with `location_type` of 1, and the other with 3?  All you're filtering for is that there must be two distinct `location_type` values, and one of them must be 1 or 2.

Comment: @cdhowie : nope, 3 would never be caught.

Comment: No. I limit the search to specific types (1 and 2 in this example). When you apply having clause and count distinct values you'll be sure that all are presents.

Comment: 3 would not, but the record with 1 would.  The OP wants the (id, property_id) tuple where there exist rows with a location of both 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and help. Can you please explain the query as I need to write it for unlimited location_types & other filters. Thanks!

Comment: I think I see how the query works now.  Interesting approach.

Comment: @Dhananjay. My english is very poor. I've explained it some post above. Simply put within IN all the types you're looking for and in the having clause verify that the count is equal to the number of items you've specifiied in the IN clause. So you'll find all the property_id that matches all your criteria.

Comment: @Nick - Thanks a lot! I think it works for me. Will trouble you again if I need more help. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help you. :) Please mark the thread as solved if everything will work as expected. ;)

Comment: Nick, will it work for a table with over million entries for location_type with few hundred thousand properties and what would be the execution time? Any advise on indexing and optimizing execution time? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have your table to make serious tests. Do them on your own and if some query runs slow edit your thread, add explain at the beginning of the query and post the output. :)

Answer (score 3):

A self-join would eliminate the need for a subquery, although that doesn't mean that it will be faster; normal profiling rules apply:

```
SELECT table1.property_id
  FROM table table1
  INNER JOIN table tabel2 ON table1.property_id = table2.property_id
  WHERE table1.location_type = 1
  AND table2.location_type = 2
```

Comment: I tried the same logic and it worked for me as well but I've around 15 different location_type which needs to be nested with other filters as well. Can you advise on resolving the overhead?